# Running python script from windows batch file - filename conflicts

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have a python script `script.py` designed to run at the command line. To make it easier to run, I have a windows batch file `script.bat` which sets up some defaults and other things. They exist in the same directory.

If I run `>script` at the command prompt, then the python script is run preferentially to the batch file. `>script.bat` works as expected.

`>where script` lists the batch file first, so to my understanding, it should be run preferentially to the python script.

Can I ensure that the batch file is run preferentially without renaming or using the file extension?

Answer (score 3):

the order of `where` is not the order it will execute. Where lists files in the local path first, in alphabetic order, then will it list the names in the environment path. So assume in the working `dir` you have files:

```
test
test.bat
test.cmd
test.py
```

that is how they will be listed, alphabetically.

which executes first is a matter of order from the `pathext` variable, an example, by running `set pathext` from `cmd`:

```
PATHEXT=.PY;.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PYW
```

In this modified version, I placed `.py` first, meaning that if only the name is specified it run by the extension in the order of the list. So given your example of only the 2 similar files with extensions `.bat` and `.py` here `script.py` will be launched first.. So if I move it to the end:

```
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
```

Now if we run `script` will it launch the `.bat` first.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not `where` but the file system (NTFS) that does the alphabetic sorting. And `where` also uses the `PATHEXT` variable…

Comment: @aschipfl, correct, I meant rather that where will list alphabetically and has no relation to the executable extension order.

Comment: Oh, you're right; even the extensions become sorted alphabetically (by whatever), I wasn't aware of that, I thought `where` returns them in the order they appear in `PATHEXT`, but obviously I was wrong…

Answer (score 0):

Solved by making my script into a zip file containing a **main**.py. `script.pyz` runs after the batch.